# CSS Fixed position property giving troubles

Tags: css

I have the following div that I want to remain fixed at the top of the window:

```
<div class="head"> <img scr="website.jpg" id="heading">
  <div id="nav"> <a href="pro.html"><img src="tag1.jpg"></a> | 
      <a href="forum.html"><img src="tag2.jpg"></a> | 
      <a href="glr.html"><img src="tag3.jpg"></a> | 
      <a href="cus.html"><img src="tag4.jpg"></a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I was able to style the above 2 divs successfully, but when I try to add

```
.head{
 position:fixed;
 }
```

the div is thrown downwards, leaving quite some space above it.
I tried removing all the `margin:top` instances but that didn't help. What could be wrong?

Comment: Give it a `top` and `left` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a position too, so:

```
position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;
```